# Ajax tab container returning Java Script Error

Tags: asp.net, tabcontainer

I trying to use a Tab Container control in a asp.net web-page and it's returning 'Object doesn't support this property or method" java script error when opening in browser.  Using .NET 3.5, AjaxControlToolKit 4.1.7.1213 and I.E. 8.  What is wrong with the below code?  The first part of the code is surrounded in "" because it would not appear in my posting. Thanks.

"<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShortSaleInvestorReview.aspx.cs" Inherits="ShortSaleInvestorReview.WebUI.Pages.ShortSaleInvestorReview" %>
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajax" %>"

```
<ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" >
    <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
    </ajax:TabPanel>
    <ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
    </ajax:TabPanel>
    <ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
    </ajax:TabPanel>
</ajax:TabContainer>
```

---

The JScript debugger stops at:    self._tabIndex = opt.owner.get_tabs().length;

The above markup seems to have an issue with the actual AJAX Jscript (jQuery.Tabs.TabPanel.debug.js)

// Name:        jQuery.Tabs.TabPanel.debug.js
// Assembly:    AjaxControlToolkit
// Version:     4.1.7.1213
// FileVersion: 4.1.7.1213
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
(function(window, $) {

```
$act.createWidget('tabPanel', $.Widget, {

    options: {
        enabled: true,
        scrollBars: "None",
        dynamicServicePath: null,
        dynamicServiceMethod: null,
        dynamicContextKey: null,
        onDemandMode: "Always",
        updatePanelID: null,
        wasLoadedOnce: false,
        owner: null           
    },

    _events: ["click", "populating", "populated"],

    _create: function() {
        var self = this, 
            opt = self.options,
            elId = self.element.attr('id');

        self._active = false;
        self._tab = $('#' + elId + "_tab");
        self._header = $("#__tab_" + elId);
        self._tabIndex = opt.owner.get_tabs().length;

        if (opt.enabled) {
            self._addHandlersOnEnabled();
        } else {
            self._makeEnabled(false);
        }

        if (opt.onClientClick) {
            self.add_click(opt.onClientClick);
        }
    },
```

Comment: add more info on error and error line ?

Comment: Webpage Error:  Line 32: Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: and which line is that?

Comment: self._tabIndex = opt.owner.get_tabs().length;

Comment: The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method" File: jQuery.Tabs.TabPanel.debug.js Line: self._tabIndex = opt.owner.get_tabs().length; This is a known issue when you use the TabContainer control in asp.net with IE8. You can try to use IE9 IE10 to view it. And Please vote it from below. http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27625 http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27597 And you can try below solution in the similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347849/ajax-tabcontainer-not-rendering-tabs-in-ie8